# Jumping to a particular node in adobe Flex Tree

Tags: apache-flex, tree, adobe

I have a flee tree that is inside a canvas component and I colapse the tree and then I want to click a button that brings me to a particlue node in the tree. I need to expand the tree which I can do but I am having issues setting the focus to a particluar node in the tree. the tree is binded to an xmlcollection.

this is the code that I am calling currently that does not work. I pass an id value and open the tree and then nothing gets selected

```
var _iAlbum_ID:String = photosList.selectedItem.album_id; 

for (var i:int = 0; i < treeMyAlbums.dataProvider.length; i ++)
{
    treeMyAlbums.expandChildrenOf(treeMyAlbums.dataProvider[i], true)
}

var node:XML = xmlMyAlbums.descendants("node").(@album_id == _iAlbum_ID)[0];
treeMyAlbums.selectedItem = node;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if 'node' is the same object as is present in the dataprovider of your tree. If it is not pointing to the same object in memory, it will not work. You can normally easily check this with the debugger.

If this is the case, you need to find back the 'node' object in the dataprovider by doing checks on one or more unique properties and use that other object to set the `selectedItem` property.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the attribute `@album_id` was case sensitive.